# "The webpage at chrome-extension://myextensionid/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_UNEXPECTED"

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-router, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing a react chrome extension.

I have a footer bar to navigate across my pages(components).

I am using react-router-dom to switch/route between pages.
My extension works perfectly when debugging but, after I build it (`npm run build`) and Load Unpacked at my extensions, the first page renders good but when I click my footer navigation buttons, my extension shows this message:

> The webpage at chrome-extension://myextensionid/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web
>   address. ERR_UNEXPECTED

Is it because I did not publish it yet, routing only works after I publish my extension?

Any ideas what can be wrong, can you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually

Comment: `chrome://flags/#network-service` might be causing the bug - it's not ready to be used so disable it.